# Convert 2 lists in a python dictionary

Tags: python, list, sqlite, dictionary

I got a long list of information through sqlite3. I've created 2 lists, the first one is made up of the first elements (Vercelli, Vercelli ecc). The second list is composed by the seconds elements (viale dell'Aeronautica, piazza Cesare Battisti). I would like to create a dictionary which join the first list's elements as keys and the second list's element as value. But I would also like to create a dictionary that groups values ​​under a single key (see the example below the code). When I try python it shows me the key with only the last value. I would be very happy if someone tried to help me

```
conntta = sqlite3.connect("Database.db")
cursortta = conntt.cursor()
sqltta = cursortt.execute("select np,id from orari")




#Sqlite3

    ('Vercelli', "viale dell'Aeronautica")
    ('Vercelli', 'piazza Cesare Battisti')
    ('Vercelli', 'Autostazione corso Gastaldi')
    ('Caresanablot', 'SP230/via Aldo Moro')
    ('Quinto v.se', 'Regione Bivio')
    ('Oldenico', 'SS594 (peso pubblico)')
    ('Albano', 'piazza Roma (chiesa)')
    ('Greggio', 'piazza Roma (posta)')
    ('Arborio', 'corso Umberto I (chiesa)')
    ('Ghislarengo', 'piazza Umberto I (posta)')
    ('Lenta', 'via XXV Luglio (municipio)')
    ('Gattinara', 'corso Vercelli (ospedale)')
    ('Gattinara', 'piazza Mazzini (stazione)')
    ('Gattinara', 'via Volta (ist.Ragion.-Geom.)')
    ('Romagnano', 'SS142 Ponte Sesia')
    ('Romagnano', 'via XXV Luglio')
    ('Serravalle', 'Vintebbio (fr.chiesa)')
    ('Serravalle', 'Piane via dei Ceri/S.Giacomo')
    ('Serravalle', 'p.za I Maggio (scuole)')
    ('Serravalle', 'Bornate Corso Valsesia')
    ('Borgosesia', 'Agnona (ITIS)')
    ('Borgosesia', 'San Rocco c.so Vercelli')
    ('Borgosesia', "v.le Duca d'Aosta (IPSIA)")
    ('Borgoseisa', 'via Antongini')
    ('Borgosesia', 'v.le Varallo/p.le Milanaccio')
    ('Borgosesia', 'Centro sportivo Milanaccio')
    ('Quarona', 'piazza Combattenti')
    ('Quarona', 'Doccio (scuole)')
    ('Varallo', 'Roccapietra via Varalli (posta)')
    ('Varallo', 'piazza Marconi (stazione)')
    ('Varallo', 'piazza Marconi (stazione)')
    ('Varallo', 'Istituto Caimi')
    ('Varallo', 'Istituto Alberghiero')
    ('Varallo', 'piazza Marconi (stazione)')
    ('Varallo', 'Valmaggia bivio Cantone')
    ('Vocca', 'Chiesa (fr.municipio)')
    ('Balmuccia', 'bivio Rimasco')
    ('Balmuccia', 'via Roma (scuole)')
    ('Scopa', 'Salterana (fr. posta)')
    ('Scopello', 'piazzale (bivio per Mera)')
    ('Pila', 'SS299/via Centro')
    ('Piode', 'SS299 via Umberto I')
    ('Campertogno', 'SS299 piazzale (fr.posta)')
    ('Mollia', 'SS299 bivio Rusa')
    ('Riva Valdobbia', 'Piazza Mercato')
    ('Alagna', 'piazzale (lungo Sesia)')

list1 = []
list2 = []
for cd in sqltta:
    list1.append(cd[0])
    list2.append(cd[1])


#Here I can't go further
```

Current Output:

```
{'Vercelli' : 'Autostazione corso Gastaldi', 'Caresanablot', 'SP230/via Aldo Moro'ecc... } #Here the other values ​​of vercelli are missing
```

Example (of what i want):

```
{'Vercelli': 'viale dell'Aeronautica', 'piazza Cesare Battisti', 'Autostazione corso Gastaldi  ecc}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just build your dictionary by appending `id` values into lists indexed by `np` values:

```
result = {}
sqltta = cursortt.execute("select np,id from orari")
for np, id in sqltta:
    if np in result:
        result['np'].append(id)
    else:
        resul['np'] = [id]
```

Comment: where is the dictionary? i cant understand?

Comment: `result` is the dictionary.

Comment: Your code is partially correct. Because i need a single dictionary, with all key/values. And if there are multiple identical keys to group them.

Answer (score 1):

```
conntta = sqlite3.connect("Database.db")
cursortta = conntt.cursor()
sqltta = cursortt.execute("select np,id from orari")

your_first_dict = dict(sqltta) # yes, that's all that is needed!

from collections import defaultdict
your_second_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in sqltta:
    your_second_dict[k].append(v)
```

Be warned though that `your_first_dict` **will** contain only the last entry for a given key - that's the nature of `dict` type, you can't have multiple entries with the same key. `your_second_dict` will have lists as values.

Comment: Where is the dictionary. What have i to print to check?

Comment: That `defaultdict` is so nice way to do this.

Comment: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}), that is when i try to do print(your_second_dict)

Comment: variables `your_first_dict` and `your_second_dict` are the dictionaries. You can give list of tuples to `dict` constructor and it generates you a dict where fist value of tuple is key and second is a value. And on second example @Blotosmetek populate dictionary in for loop.

Comment: I cant understand, where is the dictionary? I have to work on it. Can you send me a code example?

Comment: your_second_dict is an empty dictionary

Comment: It shouldn't be empty, unless you `sqltta` happens to be empty (due to an error while connecting to database?)

Comment: No but, i've another problem. when i make print(dict(sqllta)). Output: {'Vercelli':''Autostazione corso Gastaldi', 'Caresanablot': 'SP230/via Aldo Moro'} not {'Vercelli':['Autostazione corso Gastaldi',  'piazza Cesare Battisti',  'Autostazione corso Gastaldi'], 'Caresanablot': ['SP230/via Aldo Moro']